# when I click to open xworkspace file on xcode it opens .xcodeproject file instead and pods are also shown in .xcodeproject file

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFHd8.png)

when I click to open xworkspace file on xcode it opens .xcodeproject file instead and pods are also shown in .xcodeproject file. any way to make them separate again so that it can be worked on separately..?

Comment: Are you saying your pods project is shown inside of your app's project or that the pod project shows below your app's project in the Project Navigator?

Comment: I have uploaded the image, how it exactly looks inside the xcode, can you please have a look at it..?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to look